# invalid address <br> at anonymous:1:1

Tags: solidity, web3js

I wrote the following contract and instead of returning a hash value it is giving me the following error:

```
invalid address
<br>    at web3.js:3887:15
<br>    at web3.js:3713:20
<br>    at web3.js:4939:28
<br>    at web3.js:4938:12
<br>    at web3.js:4964:18
<br>    at web3.js:4989:23
<br>    at web3.js:4055:16
<br>    at web3.js:4141:16
<br>    at anonymous:1:1
```

The contract is as follows:

```
contract Unique {

    string sm;
    string bm;
    bytes32 val;
    bytes32 vm;

    function hk(string s, string y, bytes32 i)returns (bytes32){
        sm =s;
        bm =y;
        vm =i;
        val = sha3(sm,bm,vm);
    }

    function getOut()constant returns (bytes32){
        return val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read this for tutorials: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features

Then the answer is:

First:

```
var = sha3("kanekidev");
```

Second:

You should add: `pragma solidity ^0.4.0;` (or any version)

Then, the error on 1:1 seems to be an invisible character before the word `"contract"`

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you please update my code with your correct statement?

Comment: just delete manually `contract` then rewrite the word again. It seems you got a escape invisible character before the c.

Comment: Wow, how did you notice? :-)

Comment: @5chdn well the error log he posted: `at anonymous:1:1` made me suspect. It's a common issue that happens oftenly.